# How to display text on image using MVC approach

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to mvc5 and i am under a situation where I have to show  Label on an image (Not inside, If possible then please let me know the way to so also).

My lablel contains a text and i want to display that text on that image.
Please see below (My try):

```
<li class="odd">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="btn_dashboard" onclick="return BackToHome();">
        <span><label class="LabelCSSTop">@DateTime.Now.Day  </label>  </span> //This is my text which dislay above the image (not on the image, I also want to increase its defaut size)
        <span class="head-icon head-dashboard" style="margin-top: -15px;"></span> //This displays the image below the text displayed in line above.
    </a>
</li>
```

Yes ofcourse it will display the image below the text (i mean DateTime.Now.Day) as the code written do so. But is there any way so that i would be able to have that text just on the center of image ? (with size more than default size)

Comment: I don't understand. Where is your image? Supplied by CSS? In that case you could just set the image as the background of a div and write into the div? Or are you talking about watermarking?

Comment: @rism No its not about watermarking. Yes i am supplying by css. Could you please explain me what do you mean by setting the image as teh background of a div and write to a div. in detail below so that i will mark it as answer by undertsanding properly ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming we are on the same page, you could have a div with your content:

```
<div class="divination"> 
   <span><label class="LabelCSSTop">@DateTime.Now.Day  </label>  </span>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS have a `divination` class:

```
.divination{
  height: 50px; // height of div
  display: table-cell; // makes the div behave like a table cell for text content
  vertical-align: middle; // vertically aligns the text content not the image
  background-image: url(../images/divbg.png) // sets the background image. Note: path  is relative to the css file
}
```

You'll need to ensure that `LabelCSSTop` class doesn't override the divs content settings.

Comment: thanks it worked for me but i also want increase the size of text(as i discussed in question also)  i am displaying using label. But i am not able to find any font size  property. Could u plz help me

Comment: Change the CSS for the LabelCSSTop class to set a font-size:16px etc.

Comment: I already tried but do not work..please see = .LabelCSSTop {font-size:16px; } Its still show the same size.

Comment: Right click the element in Chrome and choose Inspect Element. Then on the styles tab look and see what styles are being applied and from where and change as necessary. If that doesn't help then you'll need to open another question.